# Как взаимодействовать с файлами в react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, файлы, файловая-система, react-native

У меня есть приложение на react native под android (не планируется выход на IOS). Оно должно считывать и записывать файлы из файловой системы пользователя включая файлы других приложений. Теперь вопрос: как в react native читать и записывать файлы? я не нашел ничего по моему запросу в интернету, а просто читать и записывать файлы как в NodeJS тут нельзя (по крайней мере у меня это не получилось). Заранее спасибо)

Comment: первая сссылка в google https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

Comment: спасибо большое. я просто искать походу не умею. тупой короче

Comment: даже заголовок вопроса даёт ссылку на эту библиотеку в первом же результате